# How to Sync/Mirror Two Folders with a Batch File?

Tags: batch-file

I am writing an automated backup program that can be scheduled with Task Scheduler.
I've got it done to the point where it will successfully make sure that it can read/write both the source and destination folders, then copy everything from the source to the destination, ignoring files that haven't been changed. What I want to do is "sync" the destination folder to the source folder. I've tried making it echo the filenames from `%destdir%` (variable for the inputted destination path) into a .txt file, then compare the .txt file to the filenames in `%sourcedir%` (variable for the inputted source path), deleting anything that isn't listed in the .txt file. This works on paper, but I think my syntax may be wrong, as I'm not entirely familiar with `if` and `for`. This is what the backup routine looks like so far:

```
echo Copying files...
xcopy /s/e /y /h /k /z /d /i %sourcedir% %destdir%
for /r "%destdir%" %%F in (*.*) do echo %%F>> list.txt
for /F "tokens=2* delims=\" %%I in (list.txt) do if not exist "%sourcedir%" del "%destdir%"
del list.txt
pause
if %errorlevel%==0 goto success
if %errorlevel%==gtr 0 goto failure
```

I must be doing something wrong here (my guess is `for /F "tokens=2* delims=\" %%I in (list.txt) do if not exist "%sourcedir%" del "%destdir%"`. Something about that doesn't seem right, but I can't quite put my finger on it. I've been debugging for a good hour or so now, and I can't seem to fix this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `for /F ... %%I in (...) do `<shouldn't it do something with `%%I`?

Answer (score 1):

```
ECHO Copying files...

SET "SOURCEDIR=Dir to copy"
SET "DESTDIR=Dir where the files shoud be"

XCOPY /s/e /y /h /k /z /d /i "%SOURCEDIR%" "%DESTDIR%"
FOR /R "%DESTDIR%" %%F IN (*.*) DO ( ECHO %%F>> list.txt
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=\" %%I in (list.txt) DO IF NOT EXIST "%SOURCEDIR%" DEL "%DESTDIR%"
DEL list.txt

IF "%errorlevel%" EQU "0" ( goto :SUCCESS )
IF "%errorlevel%" GTR "0" ( goto :FAILURE )

:SUCCESS
<<command you want to use here.>>
GOTO :END

:FAILURE
<<command you want to use here.>>
GOTO :END

:END
EXIT /B "%ERRORLEVE%"
```